# NGINX and LUA force lowercase URI while keeping query string

Tags: nginx, lua

NOTE: Lua noob

Trying to force lowercase URI while keeping query string parameters unmodified and appended.

I was able to use **lua**  `string.lower(ngx.var.uri)` to handle the URI, but it's dropping query strings.

I have tried adding `$is_args$args` to my try files, but believe its being dropped before that.

Thinking i have to create a table with `ngx.req.get_uri_args` in **lua** and create another block to append it back after i transform the URI to lowercase.. just not sure if this is the correct approach

I haven't seen docs on how to use `ngx.req.set_uri_args` to set args on a set_by_lua_block result, instead just the initial request..

Here are the two code blocks i've tried.

```
#works for just URI, but drops query string parameters 

set_by_lua_block $uri_lowercase { return string.lower(ngx.var.uri) }

location ~ [A-Z] {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri_lowercase $uri_lowercase/ =404;
 }
```

also tried this, but does not work :(

```
       location ~ [A-Z] {
                try_files $uri $uri/ $uri_lowercase$is_args$args $uri_lowercase/$is_args$args  =404;
        }
```

any thoughts here are appreciated -- thanks gang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works, but it does an internal rewrite -- which leaves the url in the browser uppercase.

This rewrites all URIs that have uppercase, without affecting asset files
NOTE: added nginx-extras to NGINX opensource 1.14.0 on ubuntu

I modified my block as follows,

```
        set_by_lua $uri_lowercase "return string.lower(ngx.var.uri)";
        location ~ (([A-Za-z])\w+(?!(ttf|woff2|otf|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$)([^.]+$)) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host$uri_lowercase;
        }
```

Regex Explanation

`([A-Z])\w+` = Any word that contains capital letters

`(?!(ttf|woff2|otf|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$)` = negative look ahead,  Specifies a group that can not match after the main expression (if it matches, the result is discarded).

`([^.]+$)` = negated set, does not capture string that end in a dot, e.g. style.css

Answer (score 0):

```
set_by_lua $uri_lowercase "return string.lower(ngx.var.uri)";

location ~[A-Z] {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host$uri_lowercase$is_args$args;
}
```